# How to increment a @local_variable in CASE WHEN SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to increment an local_variable in SQL server 2008 inside a CASE WHEN statement.

I am attempting to identify a time in my table when a value is reset. I am currently using CASE WHEN as in the following statement

```
SELECT  cte1.Id
            ,cte1.SomeTime
            ,cte1.ValueThatGoesBackToZero
            ,CASE WHEN (cte1.ValueThatGoesBackToZero < cte2.ValueThatGoesBackToZero) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END as PartitionOverMe

FROM CTE cte1
LEFT JOIN CTE cte2 ON cte1.Id = cte2.Id and cte1.RowNumber = cte2.RowNumber + 1
```

I am getting the following result:

```
Id                                      |   SomeTime                |ValueThatGoesBackToZero |  PartitionOverMe
--------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-04 21:33:00.000 |   101.9000             |  0
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-04 21:39:00.000 |   102.0000             |  0
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-04 21:45:00.000 |   102.1000             |  0
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-05 03:31:35.000 |   0.1000               |  1
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-05 03:37:35.000 |   0.2000               |  0
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-05 03:43:35.000 |   0.3000               |  0
```

What I would like to do is use a local variable and increment it like this:

```
CASE WHEN (cte1.ValueThatGoesBackToZero < cte2.ValueThatGoesBackToZero) THEN (++@intVar)  ELSE @intVar END as PartitionOverMe
```

So that I can use the change in a ROW_NUMBER() OVER() clause in the next CTE.
The result I want will look something like this:

```
Id                                      |   SomeTime                |ValueThatGoesBackToZero |  PartitionOverMe
--------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-04 21:33:00.000 |   101.9000             |  0
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-04 21:39:00.000 |   102.0000             |  0
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-04 21:45:00.000 |   102.1000             |  0
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-05 03:31:35.000 |   0.1000               |  1
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-05 03:37:35.000 |   0.2000               |  1
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-05 03:43:35.000 |   0.3000               |  1
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-05 03:45:35.000 |   0.1000               |  2
0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847    |   2015-03-05 03:50:35.000 |   0.2000               |  2
```

Is there a way of performing the increment of a local variable like this in the query?

Edit:

This is an example of the original data set:

```
Id      |IdOfObject                             |   SomeTime                |ValueThatGoesBackToZero
--------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-04 21:33:00.000 |   101.9000             
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-04 21:39:00.000 |   102.0000             
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-04 21:45:00.000 |   102.1000             
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-05 03:31:35.000 |   0.1000  
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-05 03:37:35.000 |   0.2000  
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-05 03:43:35.000 |   0.3000  
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-05 03:45:35.000 |   0.1000  
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-05 03:50:35.000 |   0.2000  
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-04 21:33:00.000 |   101.9000             
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-04 21:39:00.000 |   102.0000             
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-04 21:45:00.000 |   102.1000             
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-05 03:31:35.000 |   0.1000  
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-05 03:37:35.000 |   0.2000  
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-05 03:43:35.000 |   0.3000  
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-05 03:45:35.000 |   0.1000  
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-05 03:50:35.000 |   0.2000
```

What I need to achieve is to get a total from the ValueThatGoesBackToZero column each time the value is reset for each object in IdOfObject and I only need one line with the IdOfObject, the datetime from SomeTime and the total for that group.

From the above example the result I want is:

```
Id      |IdOfObject                             |   SomeTime                | Total
--------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|------
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-04 21:45:00.000 | 0.2
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-05 03:43:35.000 | 0.2
Guid    |0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847   |   2015-03-05 03:50:35.000 | 0.1 
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-04 21:45:00.000 | 0.2
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-05 03:43:35.000 | 0.2   
Guid    |CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816   |   2015-03-05 03:50:35.000 | 0.1
```

Comment: There's no straightforward way to do that - but we may do better if you can tell us what the original data is and what the final desired result is - maybe there's a way to reach the final result with fewer/different steps to the ones you've currently broken it down into.

Comment: I will add my original data, thanks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I added my data and example results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
declare @int int=0
select  @int=@int+(case when yourcolumn='something' then 0 else 1 end)  from yourtable
select @int
```

For your example

```
CASE WHEN @intVar=@intVar+(case when cte1.ValueThatGoesBackToZero < cte2.ValueThatGoesBackToZero THEN 1  ELSE 0 END)
```

But you cannot increment variable and select column or variable value in a same query

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:

```sql
declare @t table (Id varchar(17), IdOfObject uniqueidentifier,
    SomeTime datetime,ValueThatGoesBackToZero decimal(17,4))
insert into @t(Id,IdOfObject,SomeTime,ValueThatGoesBackToZero) values
('Guid','0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847','2015-03-04T21:33:00.000',101.9000),
--Full sample data removed from script
('Guid','CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816','2015-03-05T03:50:35.000',0.2000  )

;With Ord as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IdOfObject ORDER BY SomeTime) rn
    from @t
), GroupStarts as (
    select o1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o1.IdOfObject ORDER BY o1.rn) as gn
    from Ord o1
        left join
         Ord o2 on
                o1.rn = o2.rn + 1 and
                o2.ValueThatGoesBackToZero < o1.ValueThatGoesBackToZero
    where   o2.Id is null
), GroupEnds as (
    select o1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o1.IdOfObject ORDER BY o1.rn) as gn
    from Ord o1
        left join
        Ord o2  on
                o1.rn = o2.rn -1 and
                o2.ValueThatGoesBackToZero > o1.ValueThatGoesBackToZero
    where   o2.Id is null
)
select
    gs.Id,      gs.IdOfObject,      ge.SomeTime,
    ge.ValueThatGoesBackToZero - gs.ValueThatGoesBackToZero as Total
from
    GroupStarts gs
        inner join
    GroupEnds ge
        on
            gs.IdOfObject = ge.IdOfObject and   gs.gn = ge.gn
```

Result:

```
Id                IdOfObject                           SomeTime                Total
----------------- ------------------------------------ ----------------------- --------
Guid              0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847 2015-03-04 21:45:00.000 0.2000
Guid              0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847 2015-03-05 03:43:35.000 0.2000
Guid              0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847 2015-03-05 03:50:35.000 0.1000
Guid              CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816 2015-03-04 21:45:00.000 0.2000
Guid              CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816 2015-03-05 03:43:35.000 0.2000
Guid              CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816 2015-03-05 03:50:35.000 0.1000
```

The logic being that we can (having numbered the rows once, in `Ord`) identify the start and end row for each "Group" by finding the rows which don't have a predecessor with a lower value (for `GroupStarts`) and rows which don't have a successor with a higher value (for `GroupEnds`). We can then just join those rows together, having used `ROW_NUMBER()` again to work out the group numbers.

---

The full insert for the above script was actually:

```
declare @t table (Id varchar(17), IdOfObject uniqueidentifier,
    SomeTime datetime,ValueThatGoesBackToZero decimal(17,4))
insert into @t(Id,IdOfObject,SomeTime,ValueThatGoesBackToZero) values
('Guid','0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847','2015-03-04T21:33:00.000',101.9000),
('Guid','0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847','2015-03-04T21:39:00.000',102.0000),
('Guid','0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847','2015-03-04T21:45:00.000',102.1000),
('Guid','0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847','2015-03-05T03:31:35.000',0.1000  ),
('Guid','0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847','2015-03-05T03:37:35.000',0.2000  ),
('Guid','0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847','2015-03-05T03:43:35.000',0.3000  ),
('Guid','0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847','2015-03-05T03:45:35.000',0.1000  ),
('Guid','0D8EA39B-CF23-4696-8891-229C16654847','2015-03-05T03:50:35.000',0.2000  ),
('Guid','CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816','2015-03-04T21:33:00.000',101.9000),
('Guid','CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816','2015-03-04T21:39:00.000',102.0000),
('Guid','CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816','2015-03-04T21:45:00.000',102.1000),
('Guid','CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816','2015-03-05T03:31:35.000',0.1000  ),
('Guid','CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816','2015-03-05T03:37:35.000',0.2000  ),
('Guid','CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816','2015-03-05T03:43:35.000',0.3000  ),
('Guid','CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816','2015-03-05T03:45:35.000',0.1000  ),
('Guid','CA720487-D7D9-491D-A828-4697C30F4816','2015-03-05T03:50:35.000',0.2000  )
```

But it's removed above to allow the actual solution to appear without (hopefully) scrolling.

Comment: This is great. Works on SQL fiddle but for some reason I am not getting the GroupEnds for any object with more than 1 group when I am working on my real data set.

Comment: Actually after doing some more SQL fiddle I found that this doesn't give the expected results. This is the example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6041/5